Problema con formula para pasar un saldo a otra celda
Necesito crear una tabla de gastos compartidos y salio todo bien, pero me quede encerrado en una parte.
Como se puede ver en la imagen tengo dos columnas que son las importantes la D y la E
Si el dato de columna D tiene en columna E nombre Fede, se sumara en J2 y lo mismo pasa si tiene en E nombre Ani, se sumará en G2, al mismo tiempo estos 2 datos se proratean en la columna i2, diciendo quien le debe a quien.
Hasta ahi voy bien, luego esta FedeS y AniS que son gastos individuales los cuales no afectan a la cuenta de i2
Mi problema es cuando quiero idear una forma de cancelar el pago, por ejemplo que Ani le pague los 25$ a Fede y que ahora la columna I2 muestre que no hay deuda, trate de hacer columnas auxiliares ( N y O) en donde atravez de columna E ingresando FedeD y AniD sumen ahi y pueda trabajar con eso, pero no logro hacerlo.

Todo esto debo reflejarlo en una pestaña de saldos que ya tiene toda la suma hecha (entre las 3 pestañas), pero me falta sumarle este ultimo tema en caso que funcione esta "cancelacion" de saldo


Se entiende que es en la columna I donde tiene que aparecer que no hay deuda, por ende, el problema es en esa celda de la columna I, solo que te falto mostrar la formula que tienes ahora.

No tengo claro si este diseño es el más adecuado. ¿quieres restar 25 a lo de Ani porque en la columna N tienes puesto que Ani Pago a fede?
